# What series are there after Rurouni Kenshin (1995)?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

It seems that after Rurouni Kenshin (1995), there are more stories. But I don't know what to watch because it shows that Kenshin and Kaoru has a baby, Kenshin's past and also that Kaoru was kidnapped by some guys hiding a grudge on Kenshin.

But I'm not sure if there is a movie or different part of the series like season two or something.

Comment: If you want to know all the different movies and OVAs, I'd suggest just checking out the wikipedia page for Rurouni Kenshin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final arc of the *Rurouni Kenshin* manga is indeed about a man, Enishi, who has an old grudge against Kenshin. **However, the final arc of the manga was never put into the anime.** There do exist two OVA series that adapt this part of the anime.

The [*Trust and Betrayal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin:_Trust_%26_Betrayal) OVAs adapts the backstory of the final arc, and the [*Reflection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin:_Reflection) OVAs adapts the final arc, though it only appears as a lengthy flashback. The main story of *Reflection* takes place after the manga.

Both sets of OVAs are drastically different in style and tone from the manga and anime, and lots of content from the manga is not present due to the brevity of the OVAs. That being said, they were highly praised. They were released in English under the *Samurai X* name.

Comment: ^ So theirs only two after Rurouni Kenshin called Trust and Betrayal & Reflection and with the guy was never put into an anime?

Comment: There is also an anime movie, a two episode anime that retells the Kyoto Arc (which is the one where Kenshin fights the guy wrapped in bandages),  and a series of live action movies. I can add those to my answer, but really, all the information you might need is on the wikipedia page in the sidebar.

Comment: Yea thanks so much for the help. May you also answer another question for me irrelevant to this but about the website?

Answer (score 1):

Now there are also 3 recently new live action movies made in Japan:

```
Rurôni Kenshin: Meiji kenkaku roman tan (2012)
Rurôni Kenshin: Densetsu no saigo-hen   (2014)
Rurôni Kenshin: Kyôto taika-hen         (2014)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several OVA's.
"Trust and Betrayal"
The Kyoto arc (condensed ova)
and the live action adaptation.
The manga resumed in the "Hokkaido" arc, however Nobuhiro Watsuki was arrested for facing child pornography charges, but the series is back on in 2018......